# Error on inserting multiple lines in Postgresql with Postgres.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to insert multiple rows at once in a Postgresql database by using Postgres.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres). When following the code example mentioned at https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres#multiple-inserts-in-one-query to do so, I get the following error `Max number of parameters (65534) exceeded`. I have to insert 35k rows, but I even get the error, when doing several bulks of e.g. 5k rows but therefore 7 tomes. The first time works, but the second inserts also result in the same error. Did anyone successfully insert several thousand rows at once by using this library?

This is how I am trying to insert multiple rows at once in a for-loop with `i` as a control variable ranging from 0 to 6 (incl.):

`` await this.sql`insert into crm.consumption_data ${this.sql(entriesToInsert.splice(i * 5000, (i + 1) * 5000), 'direction_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'customer_id', 'pod', 'type_id', 'version_time', 'quality', 'quantity', 'unit', 'granularity', 'updated_by', 'file_import_id')}`; ``

This is how I add the objects to the array `entriesToInsert` which holds all 35k rows. The object keys are named the same as the column names.

`entriesToInsert.push({direction_id: directionId,start_time: entry.startTime.toISOString(),end_time: entry.endTime.toISOString(),customer_id: customerId,pod: consumptionInfo.consumptionMetaData.meteringPoint,type_id: typeId,version_time: consumptionInfo.consumptionMetaData.versionTime,quality: entry.quality,quantity: entry.quantity,unit: entry.unit,granularity: granularityId,updated_by: process.env.user,file_import_id: fileId });`

What do I have to change in order to get this running?

Many thanks, Peter

Comment: 13*5000 is 65000 that is near 65534. Try to decrease to 3000-4000

Comment: Many thanks for your help! But the problem was simply caused by applying the wrong function to the array of values. I mistakenly used `splice` instead of `slice`. Such a silly bug from myself.